# Powershell cutting off output

Tags: powershell

I am using the below to see a folder structure but when i look at the transcript a chunk of the resuts have been cut off from the top - as if it is starting halfway through

```sh
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\transcripts\transcript.txt"
tree /f
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: I'm updating my answer, but it looks like `tree` is actually `tree.com`, not `tree.exe`. I am hitting multiple issues with transcribing it, but with a large enough directory structure I can reproduce your error and the number of lines is suspiciously close to 32767, the maximum value for a signed 16-bit integer. `.COM` files run in a 16-bit DOS subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same behavior with `tree /f` from a large directory tree. I don't know what is happening at this point, but I can offer a workaround:

```
tree /f 2>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath treeOutput.txt
```

You could also do the following, if you don't need to output to the console at the same time:

```
tree /f 2>&1 > treeOutput.txt
```

---

As for the issue with `tree /f`, `tree` is actually `tree.com`, not `tree.exe`, which means it actually runs in an MS-DOS subsystem. I suspect that `Start-Transcript` isn't fully compatible with `.COM` programs and I suggest using output redirection as recommended above as a suitable workaround.