# Create file list in every subfolder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, foreach-object

I'm very new to PowerShell and have basically zero knowledge about PowerShell scripting, which is why I need some help.

I have folder structure with subfolders (as shown below) for which I want to generate a filelist.txt in every 1st level subfolder using `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`.

```
Main Folder  
├───Sub 1
│   │   file.ext
│   └───Sub A
│           file.ext   
└───Sub 2 
|   |   file.ext
|   └───Sub B
└─── etc.
```

So far, I experimented with some code I found online but either I'm getting errors or absolutely nothing happens. This is the closest thing to what I want, as it creates filelist.txt files in the correct directories, but unfortunately those files are empty. In addition, a filelist.txt is created in the main folder which I don't want.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | 
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Item -ItemType file -Path "$($_.FullName)" -Name "filelist.txt"
        Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse > filelist.txt
    }
```

Any help or suggestions are very appreciated!

Comment: Should the `filelist.txt` files themselves be included in the listing?

Comment: Are you looking to export only the absolute paths on your `Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse > filelist.txt` call or what properties are you interested in exporting?

Comment: instead of using the pipeline, use a basic `foreach` loop. that will let you do one step at a time - with a pause while testing - and see EXACTLY what you are doing at each step. don't combine ANYTHING  - instead, put every step into one line and keep each step as simple and direct as possible. **_once you have that working, then you can de-clarify your code if you really want to ..._** [*grin*]

Comment: Remove `-Recurse` from first `Get-ChildItem` and add parameter `-Path "$RootPath\*"`. This enumerates first level directories only as you already have recursion in `ForEach-Object` scriptblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the immediate sub-folders of `Main Folder` you shouldn't use `-Recurse` on your first call to `Get-ChildItem -Directory` as that would give you all sub-folders recursively as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71785614/create-file-list-in-every-subfolder-using-powershell#comment126858977_71785614) pointed out in his helpful comment.

Regarding your export line:

```
Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse > filelist.txt
```

It would place the `filelist.txt` file on your current location not on the subfolders, it would also replace the file per loop iteration.

The code would look like this if I understood correctly what you were looking for:

```
Get-ChildItem 'path\to\Main Folder' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $destination = Join-Path $_.FullName -ChildPath filelist.txt
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse |
        Set-Content $destination
}
```

Worth noting that this would only export the absolute paths of the files and folders under each sub-folder of `Main Folder`, however it might be worth changing the export type to CSV to have the properties of each object as you see them on your console:

```
    $destination = Join-Path $_.FullName -ChildPath filelist.csv
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse |
        Export-Csv $destination -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That basically did the trick, thank you very much!
But would it be possible to also include the "normal"/"full" output (including path etc.) of the command  `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` or alternatively `ls -s` which you would get from the command line?

Comment: @redoXiD yup, thats what the 2nd part of my answer is referring to. It's far better to export to CSV as shown in that 2nd part

Answer (score 0):

While I normally avoid external commands when a proper solution can be found with PowerShell cmdlets, `tree /f` already does this for you. There is some [funkiness with relying on transcripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71650216/584676) to provide the directory tree but you should be able to manually redirect the output to a file without issue:

```
cd /path/to/base/folder
tree /f > filelist.txt
```

This will create `filelist.txt` relative to the directory you ran `tree /f` from, and redirect the output to `filelist.txt`. Note that if `filelist.txt` exists already in the folder tree, it will be enumerated with the rest of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.

```
##variables
$startingLocation = Get-Location
$subs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Depth 1 -Directory
$startingCheck = ($startingLocation).Path + "\filelist.txt"


##create starting list in original directory
##check if it exists already and write to it
if ( Test-Path -Path $startingCheck) {
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse >> filelist.txt
}

else {
    Write-Warning "File doesn't exist... creating file."
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $startingLocation -Name "filelist.txt"
    Write-Warning "File created."
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse >> filelist.txt
    Write-Warning "File created and now writing GCI to log."
}

##loop
foreach ($s in $subs) {

    ##go to the location
    Set-Location -Path $s.FullName -Verbose

    ##test if output file exists in current directory of loop
    $testPwd = Get-Location  -Verbose
    $currentPath = ($testPwd).Path + "\filelist.txt"
   
    ## if the file already exists - write GCI to it
    if (Test-Path -Path $currentPath) { 
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Depth 1 >> filelist.txt
        Write-Warning "File exists... writing GCI to log."
    }

    ## otherwise if there is no file, make one and write GCI to it
    else {
        Write-Warning "File doesn't exist... creating file."
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $testPwd -Name "filelist.txt"
        Write-Warning "File created."
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Depth 1 >> filelist.txt
        Write-Warning "File created and now writing GCI to log."
    }

    ##exit the loop
}
#go back to original location
Set-Location $startingLocation
```

Before:

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is A4DB-B980
C:.
│   test.ps1
│
├───Folder1
│   │   doc1.txt
│   │   doc2.txt
│   │
│   ├───FolderA
│   └───FolderB
│       └───FolderB1
│               doc1b.txt
│               doc2b.txt
│
├───Folder2
│   ├───FolderA
│   └───FolderB
└───Folder3
```

Result:

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is A4DB-B980
C:.
│   filelist.txt
│   test.ps1
│
├───Folder1
│   │   doc1.txt
│   │   doc2.txt
│   │   filelist.txt
│   │
│   ├───FolderA
│   │       filelist.txt
│   │
│   └───FolderB
│       │   filelist.txt
│       │
│       └───FolderB1
│               doc1b.txt
│               doc2b.txt
│
├───Folder2
│   │   filelist.txt
│   │
│   ├───FolderA
│   │       filelist.txt
│   │
│   └───FolderB
│           filelist.txt
│
└───Folder3
        filelist.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $BaseFolder -Depth 1
```

You can mess with the -Depth argument if you need another level.